# calculate elapsed time from repeating time series samples (laps)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data that is essentially a series of laps where each lap has its own elapsed time, but I am trying to calculate the total elapsed time.

Here's some code that has similar data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
laptime = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
lap = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
timeblocks = pd.DataFrame({'laptime': laptime, 'lap': lap})
timeblocks['timediff'] = timeblocks.laptime.diff()
timeblocks['elapsed'] = 
pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
timeblocks
```

The resulting data looks like:

```
    lap  laptime  timediff  elapsed
0     1        1       NaN        1
1     1        2       1.0        2
2     1        3       1.0        3
3     1        4       1.0        4
4     1        5       1.0        5
5     2        1      -4.0        6
6     2        2       1.0        7
7     2        3       1.0        8
8     2        4       1.0        9
9     2        5       1.0       10
10    3        1      -4.0       11
11    3        2       1.0       12
12    3        3       1.0       13
13    3        4       1.0       14
14    3        5       1.0       15
```

The elapsed time is what I actually need to calculate. I tried various forms of messing around with the time differentials and cumsum, but am kinda stuck.

Real-world data looks more like the following:

```
113.81201171875 1
113.86206054688 1
113.912109375   1
113.96215820313 1
0.05126953125   2
0.101318359375  2
0.1513671875    2
```

In the case of the real world data, the sample rate is about 0.05 sec.

Comment: `laptime` is what you are trying to accumulate?  You just want a total? What is the expected result for your example data?

Comment: 'elapsed' is the expected thing/result I want to calculate from 'laptime'. In the real world, I only have 'laptime' and 'lap' and real-world sample data is the second block.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io, operator, itertools
```

Assuming the data is in a text file or multiline string:

```
s = '''113.81201171875 1
113.86206054688 1
113.912109375   1
113.96215820313 1
0.05126953125   2
0.101318359375  2
0.1513671875    2'''
f = io.StringIO(s)
```

Gather the data into a list; sort the list by lap then time; group the data by lap and extract the largest and smallest time; calculate the elapsed lap time; acumulate.

```
data = []
for line in f:
    time, lap = map(float, line.strip().split())
    data.append((time, lap))

lap = operator.itemgetter(1)
time = operator.itemgetter(0)

data.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1,0))
total = 0
for el, times in itertools.groupby(data, lap):
    low, *_, high = map(time, times)
    elapsed = high - low
    print(f'lap {el}, elapsed time: {elapsed}')
    total += elapsed
print(f'total elapsed time: {total}')


>>>
lap 1.0, elapsed time: 0.15014648438000222
lap 2.0, elapsed time: 0.10009765625
total elapsed time: 0.2502441406300022
>>>
```